# how to write html tag in json string

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I am having trouble writing HTML tag in JSON string. I can't figure out what is wrong. 
I went through some of the similar questions but I cant try to make out whats wrong.

I am accessing the json through the session .

here is what I am doing. This is the piece of JSON I am accessing through a session

```
<textarea>[
    {
        "LastName": "Cooper",
        "title": "Provider"
    }
     ]</textarea>
```

So I want to add a html tag in this JSON and then pass to the session.

```
 <textarea>[
    {
        "LastName": "Cooper",
        "title": "<br>\"Provider\" "
    }
     ]
</textarea>
```

I am using a Jquery plugin of fullcalendar to display and event on the calendar.

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        theme:true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        events:JSON.parse(document.getElementById("populatePatientReport").innerHTML)
});
```

So I get the event on the html page. But there is no new line. 
here is the html that I get. So i get the 
 tag but three is no new line. its ignored by the browser as a string

```
<span class="something"><br>Provider</span>
```

Comment: How you get that there is no new line?

Comment: Since I can see the calender generate an event as <br>Provider 
And there is no new line visible.

Comment: Did you try to put in css: span.something br{ clear:both; }